# Stabilizers of an arbitrary element of $\mathbb Z^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions, integer-lattices

Let $G = SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ acting on  $\mathbb Z^2$ by the product $Av$, I'm trying to define $\operatorname{Stab}(v)$ for all $v\in \mathbb Z^2$.
$Av = v$, then $1$ is an eigenvalue associated with the eigenvector $v$.

For all $A\in \operatorname{Stab}(v)$, the characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^2$, then the minimal polynomial $m_A$ is $(x-1)$ or $(x-1)^2$ for Hamilton–Cayley Theorem.
If $m_A = (x-1)$, then $A = I_2$ and $I_2 \in \operatorname{Stab}(v)$.
If $m_A = (x-1)^2$, then $A$ is not diagonalizable, then the Jordan normal form of A is \begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I don't know if this is a easy way, but I can't find the solution of this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You want to determine $A$'s entries $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb  Z$ such that, given $(x,y)\in\Bbb Z^2$:
\begin{cases}
ax+by=x\\
cx+dy=y\\
ad-bc=1\\
\tag1
\end{cases}
Therefore:

- for $v= \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$, $\operatorname{Stab}(v)=\operatorname{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$;
- for $v=  \begin{pmatrix}
  x\ne 0 \\
  0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$, $\operatorname{Stab}(v)=\biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix}
  1&b \\
  0&1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}\mid b\in \Bbb Z \biggr\}$;
- for $v= \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  y\ne 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$, $\operatorname{Stab}(v)=\biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix}
  1&0 \\
  c&1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}\mid c\in \Bbb Z \biggr\}$;
- if $x\mid y$, namely for $v= \begin{pmatrix}
  x \\
  kx \\
  \end{pmatrix}$, for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, $(1)$ yields $a+kb=1$, $c+kd=k$ and $d-bk=1$, and finally:
  \begin{alignat}{1}
  &bk=d-1\\
  &a=2-d\\
  &c=k(1-d)
  \end{alignat}
  So:
  $$\operatorname{Stab}(v)=\biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix}
  2-d&\frac{d-1}{k} \\
  -k(d-1)&d \\
  \end{pmatrix}\mid d-1\in k\Bbb Z\biggr\}$$
- if $x\nmid y$, then $b=lx$ and $d=1+mx$ for some $l,m\in\Bbb Z$, whence $a=1-ly$ and $c=-my$. So:
  \begin{alignat}{1}
  \operatorname{Stab}(v) &= \biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix}
  1-ly&lx \\
  -my&1+mx \\
  \end{pmatrix}\mid mx=ly, \text{ with }m,l\in\Bbb Z\biggr\} \\
  &= \biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix}
  1-mx&lx \\
  -my&1+mx \\
  \end{pmatrix}\mid mx=ly, \text{ with }m,l\in\Bbb Z\biggr\} \\
  \end{alignat}